# Set a formula in a cell of the sheet

Tags: c#, smartsheet-api

Does anyone have an example of how to define a formula in a cell?

I have this, but in the sheet it says unparseable:

```
new Cell
{
    ColumnId = columnMapA["Sociedad"],
    Formula = "=VLOOKUP([# de servicio]" + Rownumber + "; {Catálogo de Materiales Rango 1}; 2; false)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is the only problem but you should use commas as argument separators, not semicolons, i.e.

```
new Cell
{
    ColumnId = columnMapA["Sociedad"],
    Formula = "=VLOOKUP([# de servicio]" + Rownumber + ", {Catálogo de Materiales Rango 1}, 2, false)"
}
```

Comment: do you have some example?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to include a row number in the cell using "@row". That information can be found here:

https://help.smartsheet.com/articles/2476491-create-efficient-formulas-with-at-cell

Also, I'm not sure about language settings in SmartSheet, but you could try writing the word "Range" in English and see if that helps.

Here's an example I've used:

```
 new Cell
 {
     ColumnId = COLUMNID,
     Formula = "=VLOOKUP([# de servicio]@row, {Catálogo de Materiales Range 1}, 2, false)"
 }
```

You could also try changing the last parameter to 'true'. That tells VLOOKUP to find an approximate match instead of an exact match.